# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases in linear regression

Tags: r, na, lm

I am trying to do come [lm](/questions/tagged/lm) with [r](/questions/tagged/r). I think I'm having problems with `NA` values, but I can't figure it out.

If I try to do a regression with only two variables, the result is there but with a very low R2 (perhaps too low to be normal).

```
Model_1 <- lm(Participation ~ Economy, data = Country1)
```

The result is:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.211762   0.008488  24.948  < 2e-16 ***
Economy     0.180346   0.061407   2.937  0.00335 ** 
Multiple R-squared:  0.00359,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.003174
```

However, when I try to fit many variables, I systematically get the error `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases`.
I have also tried adding `na.action = 'na.exclude'`, but the result does not change. Any ideas?

The code:

```
Model_2 <- lm(data = Country1, Participation ~ Economy + Male + Young + Low_Income + High_Education + Low_Education + Pol_Interest + Gov_satisf + Trust_Parliament + Redistribution + No_protection + Gov_respons + Ref_all + Ref_none + Voters + Religious + Corr_national + Corr_local + Life_Quality + Internet_user + Employed + Unemployed + Student + Emp_Public, na.action = "na.exclude")
```

The result:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message gives you a clear problem statement.   `0 (non-NA) cases`

when you expand to consider all the variables that you listed out, there are 0 cases (i.e. 0 rows) that are complete.

There is not any row that doesn't have at least one NA.

You should investigate your data and understand the distribution of NA's.

This can lead you off in many directions, from deciding that one variable is entirely useless (a whole column of NA's ?), and simply dropping it, at one extreme, to using forms of missing value imputation, to plug the holes, on the other. But it all starts with investigating your data.